# ¿Cómo puedo lanzar una excepción que instancíe un objeto?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, excepciones

Estoy empezando en el tema de las raise exeptions y estoy tratando de efectuar una operacion sencilla. Sin embargo, no funciona mi código:

```
class errores(Exception):
    def __int__(self,numero1,numero2):
        self.num1 = numero1
        self.num2 = numero2

    def error(self):
        return print("los numero {} {} no efectuaron la operacion".format(self.num1,self.num2))

try:
    def operaciones(operacion):
        def suma(x,y):
            return print(x+y)

        def resta(x,y):
            return print(x-y)

        lista = {'+':suma,'-':resta}

        return lista[operacion]
        raise errores
except errores as e:
    e.error()

pt = operaciones('*')
pt(10, 3)
```

Estoy trabajando con funciones de orden superior y empezando tambien con programacion funcional.

Pero no comprendo qué falla al lanzar la exepción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código tiene varios problemas:

- Los nombres de clase deben comenzar por mayúscula, es decir, en lugar de `errores` tu excepción debería llamarse `Errores`. Mejor aún, dale un nombre más significativo que describa mejor qué tipo de error se produce. Por ejemplo `ErrorOperacion` o similar.
- El constructor debe ser `__init__()` en vez de `__int__()`
- El bloque `try/catch` está mal colocado. Lo tienes alrededor del `def operaciones()`, pero ese bloque no puede producir ninguna excepción (ni aún si la lanzas con `raise`) ya que todo lo que hace es definir una función. La excepción no se lanzaría hasta que esa función *se ejecute*.

  Es decir, el bloque `try/catch` debería estar alrededor de las líneas `pt=operaciones('*')` y `pt(10,3)`.
- El constructor de tu error espera dos números, por tanto cuando lo instancies en el `raise` tendrías que pasarle dos números, como por ejemplo `raise ErrorOperacion(x,y)`. Pero el problema es que `x` e `y` no están definidos en el punto en que intentas lanzar la excepción, ya que son parámetros de `suma()` o `resta()`, pero no de `operaciones()`.
- Tu `raise` nunca llega a ejecutarse, puesto que va después de una instrucción `return` tras la cual ya no se ejecuta más código de esa función. De todas formas, aún si no estuviera después del `return`, las excepciones se lanzan cuando se detecta algún problema, por lo que debería estar dentro de algún `if`. De lo contrario esa excepción se lanzará siempre al llegar a esa línea.
- El intento de acceder a `lista[operacion]` va a generar otra excepción si la `operacion` no está en la lista (como es el caso con el  `*`). Esta excepción es del tipo `KeyError` que tu código no maneja.
- El método `error` de la excepción no debería imprimir nada, sino retornar una cadena para que la imprima quien lo llame.
- Lo mismo para las operaciones `sumar()` y `restar()`. Las funciones en general no deben imprimir sus resultados, sino retornarlos para que los imprima quien las llamó. Y en todo caso no tiene sentido que hagas un `return print()`, ya que `print` en sí mismo devuelve `None` y por tanto ese sería el valor que estaría retornando tu función.

No sé muy bien cómo arreglar todo esto, ya que no tengo claro qué tenías en mente al pasar dos números al constructor del error. Yo creo que lo mejor sería tener dos excepciones diferentes, una para detectar si la operación no es correcta (que se lanzaría si `operacion` no está en `lista`) y otra para detectar si los operandos no son correctos (que se lanzaría según el valor de `x` e `y`, y por tanto dentro ya de las funciones que operan). Ambas excepciones podrían derivar de otra común, para hacer más fácil capturarlas en un solo `except`.

Así:

```
class ErroresOperacion(Exception):
  pass

class ErrorOperacionInvalida(ErroresOperacion):
  def __init__(self, operando):
    self.op = operando

  def error(self):
    return "La operacion '{}' no está soportada".format(self.op)


class ErrorOperacionOperandos(ErroresOperacion):
  def __init__(self, num1, num2):
    self.num1 = num1
    self.num2 = num2

  def error(self):
    return "Los números {} y {} no son válidos para la operación".format(
        self.num1,self.num2)

def operaciones(operacion):
    def suma(x,y):
        return x+y

    def resta(x,y):
        return x-y

    def division(x, y):
      # Ejemplo de cómo lanzar la excepcion ErrorOperacionOperandos
      if y==0:
        raise ErrorOperacionOperandos(x,y)
      return x/y

    lista = {'+': suma, '-': resta, '/': division}

    if operacion not in lista:
      raise ErrorOperacionInvalida(operacion)

    return lista[operacion]

try: 
  pt = operaciones('+')
  r = pt(10, 3)
  print(r)
  pt = operaciones('*')
  r = pt(10, 3)
  print(r)
except ErroresOperacion as e:
  print(e.error())

try:
  pt = operaciones('-')
  r = pt(10, 0)
  print(r)
  pt = operaciones('/')
  r = pt(10, 0)
  print(r)
except ErroresOperacion as e:
  print(e.error())
```

Que al ejecutarse mostrará:

```
13
La operacion '*' no está soportada
10
Los números 10 y 0 no son válidos para la operación
```